# Eclipse, Java, Midi, Linux(Debian) - sequencer issue

Tags: java, eclipse, debian, midi, jfugue

Here's the problem:

> Exception in thread "main" org.jfugue.JFugueException: The MIDI System cannot instantiate a sequencer.  Although this error is reported by JFugue, the problem is not with JFugue itself.  Find resources for using MIDI on your specific system.  The exception message from MidiSystem.getSequencer() is: null

Here's the whole code:

```
    import org.jfugue.*;
    import javax.sound.midi.*;

    public class HelloWorld {

        public static void main(String[] args){     

        MidiDevice.Info[] devices = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();

        if (devices.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("No MIDI devices found");
        } else {
            for (MidiDevice.Info dev : devices) {
                System.out.println(dev.getName());
            }
        }

        Player player = new Player();
        player.play("A B C");

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

and the output:

```
Real Time Sequencer
Exception in thread "main" org.jfugue.JFugueException: The MIDI System cannot instantiate a sequencer.  Although this error is reported by JFugue, the problem is not with JFugue itself.  Find resources for using MIDI on your specific system.  The exception message from MidiSystem.getSequencer() is: null
    at org.jfugue.Player.<init>(Player.java:82)
    at org.jfugue.Player.<init>(Player.java:65)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:20)
```

I'm running Eclipse with a package from apt-get - 'sun-java6-jdk' which unpacks itself to a jvm directory. I use JRE1.5 for compiling and 1.6 for running. I use the 1.5 for compiling because that is the version that is compatible with jfugue4.0.

This might be the issue though - my ALSA 'aplay' command does not 'play' files. I can use VLC media player or timidity from the command line, and I get sound. Also, speaker-test works. Why wouldn't command line 'aplay' work as well? Is this a symptom of the java issue?

**EDIT: aplay does work. sorry, just did a retest.**

EDIT: Here is the result of " cat /dev/sndstat/ "

> Sound Driver:3.8.1a-980706 (ALSA v1.0.24 emulation code) Kernel: Linux
>   sean-debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u2 x86_64 Config
>   options: 0
>
> Installed drivers:  Type 10: ALSA emulation
>
> Card config:  HDA ATI SB at 0xd0400000 irq 16 HDA ATI HDMI at
>   0xd0310000 irq 19
>
> Audio devices: NOT ENABLED IN CONFIG
>
> Synth devices: NOT ENABLED IN CONFIG
>
> Midi devices: NOT ENABLED IN CONFIG
>
> Timers: 31: system timer
>
> Mixers: NOT ENABLED IN CONFIG

Thanks everyone - this has been bugging me.

Comment: Just to confirm, given the edits to your question: Are you on a path to figuring this out on your own (with respect to your system's setup), or do you still need help with the JFugue library?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, I am having trouble getting any kind of sound to run in Java(Eclipse or command line) on Linux. I can get MIDI to work with other applications, and my speakers of course work in general as well. Any suggestions or experience would be great! Thanks

Comment: You could be missing a soundbank. Take a look under the Installation Instructions on this page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/soundbanks-135798.html If you find that the folder mentioned is empty, download one of the soundbanks from that page (I suggest the Deluxe one) and install it.

Comment: OK - using the 'aoss' command worked, like this:   'aoss java HelloWorld'.    Then, strangely, even after restarting the computer, I don't have to use the 'aoss' command anymore. I wish I knew why this problem happened, and why the 'aoss' fixed it permanently, but I don't! @DavidKoelle

Comment: Few things to consider: 1) Why are you using OSS emulation from ALSA instead of ALSA direcly? 2) Check your MIDI devices with: `amidi -l` 3) Check your sequencer clients and ports with `aseqdump -l` 4) Check your Playback and Capture devices with `aplay -l` and `arecord -l`, respectivaly. This is a starting point on trying to understand your system, and continue from that on.